# Hide the symbol "@" and colon ":" of order time in the WooCommerce Add new order page in backend

Tags: woocommerce

How can I hide the symbol "@" and colon ":" of order time in the WooCommerce Admin Add New order page? I've inspected the elements in Chrome to find a class or ID but not found. I know I can hide it with this code.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_style');
function my_custom_style() {
  echo '<style>
div {display: none;}
  </style>';
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jl6su.png)

Comment: What's the purpose of it ? It automatically sets the time to current time stamp. Even if you hide it, it will have the time.

Comment: I need only that it automatically sets the date and time. I don't need it to be there to manually set. To customize things I want, I try to hide elements that I don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a purpose of doing this, but if you really wish to do this, you can use input name css selectors to do it.

---

I have used **CSS** and **JS** both to get rid of `@` and `:`.

```php
add_action('admin_footer', 'bks_my_custom_style');

function bks_my_custom_style() {
    echo '
    <script>
    jQuery(function() { 
    var text = jQuery(".order_data_column_container .form-field").contents().filter(function() {
          return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
        }).remove();
     });
  </script>
  <style>
    input[name="order_date_minute"],
    input[name="order_date_hour"] 
    {
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
  ';
}
```

The code goes inside `functions.php` file.

Tested and **WORKS**.

Screenshot : [image: Updated Screenshot.]

Comment: I've have tried your code but it doesn't work. The thing is that I create an order only via the backend. I don't need that option to manually set the time and date when I create an order. So, I try to hide the element that I don't need.

Comment: How have you added the code? I rechecked and it is working. I have updated my answer with the screenshot. @catytopy

Comment: I see.  But you can see  "@ ‎ :" still remains. This is the point that I couldn't find any class or id to hide it. Sorry for less information. Actually the point is that I couldn't hide the symbol "@" and the colon ":".

Comment: Please update your question with this information. i will change my answer to cover that.

Comment: @catytopy, I have updated my answer  ( code + screenshot ). Try again.

Comment: I've updated the question. It works, thank you. Btw, it still displays on loading. It will be hidden after the loading finishes. Is there anyway to hide it on loading as well?

Comment: Try using `admin_head` instead of `admin_footer`. @catytopy

Comment: I've tried `admin_head` but still it displays on loading.

Comment: I am not able to vote, need at least 15 reputation.

Comment: As this is done, using CSS and JS, we can't really do anythin about this, without chaging wc core files, which i would never recommend. 
Yes you do need 15 reps in order to upvote. Do that once you gain that much reputation. @catytopy